# How can I turn off a dropdown menu using a media query?

Tags: javascript, html, css

(Jsfiddle for context: https://jsfiddle.net/hfwtq2c9/12/)

I've made a navbar and some links are in a dropdown menu for compactness. When the screen gets too small, it collapses all the links into a menu which can be accessed through a button. I want to make it so when it goes into the menu, all the links come out of the dropdowns and go into one list. I also have a problem where the links in my drop-down have some random whitespace on the left, and I can't figure out why it is happening. Can this be done? Thanks

My code:

```js
const primaryNav = document.querySelector(".primary-navigation");
const navToggle = document.querySelector(".mobile-nav-toggle");

navToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const visibility = primaryNav.getAttribute("data-visible");

  if (visibility === "false") {
    primaryNav.setAttribute("data-visible", true);
    navToggle.setAttribute("aria-expanded", true);
  } else if (visibility === "true") {
    primaryNav.setAttribute("data-visible", false);
    navToggle.setAttribute("aria-expanded", false);
  }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap");

* {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle,
      rgba(0, 102, 215, 1) 0%,
      rgba(15, 0, 157, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#0066d7", endColorstr="#0f009d", GradientType=1);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sr-only {
  display: none;
}

/* primary nav  */

.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.primary-header {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.primary-navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.primary-navigation a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  list-style: none;
}

.primary-navigation a:hover {
  color: #929292;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 50rem) {
  .primary-navigation {
    gap: 2rem;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    inset: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 10rem 3rem;
    flex-direction: column;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
    margin: 0;
    backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }

  .primary-navigation a {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
  }

  .primary-navigation[data-visible="true"] {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }

  .primary-header .mobile-nav-toggle {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-image: url("./assets/hamburger.svg");
    background-color: hotpink;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 2.5rem;
    border: 0;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    right: 2rem;
  }

  .primary-header .mobile-nav-toggle[aria-expanded="true"] {
    background-image: url(./assets/close.svg);
    position: fixed;
  }

  .primary-header {
    padding: 4rem;
  }
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  list-style: none;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
    <header class="primary-header flex">
      <button class="mobile-nav-toggle" aria-controls="primary-navigation" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Menu</span>
      </button>
      <nav>
        <ul data-visible="false" class="primary-navigation flex">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="about.html" class="dropbtn">About Me</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content">
              <li><a href="projects.html">My previous Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="quals.html">My Qualifications</a></li>
              <li><a href="cv.html">My CV/Resume</a></li>
              <li><a href="services.html">My Services</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="contact.html" class="dropbtn">Contact Me</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content">
              <li><a href="social.html">Social Media</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: "*I want to make it so when it goes into the menu, all the links come out of the dropdowns and go into one list.*" - Can you explain this more clearly in your question, because I honestly can't work out what this means. As far as I can tell (apart from the spacing you describe) your demo seems to do what you wish?

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirements regarding the dropdown menu? It's not clear whether you want to hide the dropdown menu on small screens or display it alongside the parent container.

Comment: @AmitRajbhandari Well at the moment in the mobile nav the dropdowns still open when you hover on the toggle, but I need it to be so all of the links that are in the dropdowns are always displayed in a vertical list like the links that actuate the dropdowns. Sorry that I wasn't very clear, I'm not really sure how to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to rid off whitespace you can add `padding-left: 0` to the `.dropdown-content` class.

```
.dropdown-content {
 // ...
 padding-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you may need to make some adjustments to the style of your `.dropdown-content`. Here's a solution that could work for you.

As for the random whitespace on the left of your dropdown links is caused by padding.

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;

  padding-left: 0; // This will remove the white space on left

  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  list-style: none;
}

@media (max-width: 50rem) {
// This keeps your dropdown visible in a small screen
  .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    padding-left: 10px; // This makes it easier to identify which children in the dropdown are linked to the parent.
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :)